# Nerve/muscle fibre depolarizaitonand repolarization balance

Tags: membrane-transport

if continously sodium is pumped in during depolarization and pottasium is pumped out during repolarization, eventually there will more sodium and less sodium inside. How the does the fibre/cell return to the balance?